# Problem getting link working with the xml data

Tags: php, xml, hyperlink

I have a problem with a project in php with xml data.
I have made a controller to fetch all the data from the xml-url and it works perfect - got all the data to output to the page but my question is how do I get to make a link that get a single instance of the xml-data.

I have made a foreach loop so I get all the data out - and have it on the page - but when I link to ?id=xxx it will not show data correctly it just takes the first instance of the xml-file.

If I use $_GET['id'] it get the selected value - but I can't the other data.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Controller
public function lodging() {
    $url = 'https://vkysten-api.bookingstudio.dk/rest/v1Admin/lodgings.xml';
    $username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $headers = array( 'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( "$username" ) );
    $response = wp_remote_get( $url, array( 'headers' => $headers ) );

    $body     = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

    $data = simplexml_load_string($body);

    return $data;
}
}

Frontpage with the link
<div class="huse">
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    @foreach ($lodging->Lodging as $lodge)
      @php
      $i++;
      $images =  $lodge->Images->Image['Location'];
      $address = $lodge['Address'];
      $postalcode = $lodge['PostalCode'];
      $city = $lodge['City'];

      $items = array();
      foreach($lodge->Images->Image as $item) {
          $items[] = $item;
      };

      usort ($items, function($a, $b) {
          return strcmp($a['SortOrder'], $b['SortOrder']);
      });

      @endphp
      @if (!empty($items))
      <div class="lodging-items">
        @foreach ($items as $item)
        <a href="feriehuse/?hus={{$address}}">
          @if ($item['SortOrder']==0)
          <div class="lodge-image">
            <img src="{{$item['Location']}}" Width="400" Height="300" alt="">
            <div class="lodge-address">{{$address}} | {{$postalcode}} {{$city}}</div>
          </div>

          @endif
          @endforeach

          <div class="frontlodge">{{$lodge->Localizations->Localization['Title']}}</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      @endif
      <?php if ($i === 8) break; ?>
    @endforeach
  </div>

Single page
<?php $item = $lodging->Lodging['Address']; ?>

@foreach ($lodging as $item)
{{$item['Address']}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a simple example of how to use SimpleXML and XPath to fetch the data...

```
$lodgings = lodging();
$id = $_GET['id'];

// Fetch the <Lodging> element with attribute Id = specific ID
$lodging = $lodgings->xpath("//Lodging[@Id='{$id}']");

// xpath returns a list of matches, so extract first one using [0]
echo $lodging[0]['Address'];
```

With `$_GET['id'] = "12";` you will get

```
Granbovej 1
```

You may want to check that `$lodging` has some elements, see if the record exists before extracting data, but it may be an assumption that your happy to make.